# Finding a generating function for a recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Let $a_1=2, a_2=10$ and $a_n=2a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}$.

I want to find the generating function, $F(x)$ for this recursion:

$$F(x) = 2 + 10x + \sum\nolimits_{n \ge 2} {(2{a_{n + 1}} + 3{a_n}) \cdot {x^n}} $$

$$F(x) = 2 + 10x + 2 \cdot \sum\nolimits_{n \ge 2} {{a_{n + 1}}{x^n} + 3}  \cdot \sum\nolimits_{n \ge 2} {{a_n}{x^n}} $$

$$F(x) = 2 + 10x + 2 \cdot \sum\nolimits_{n \ge 2} {{a_{n + 1}}{x^n} + 3}  \cdot \left( {F(x) - 2 - 10x} \right)$$

How to treat this expression?
$$\sum\nolimits_{n \ge 2} {{a_{n + 1}}{x^n}} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is even simpler than [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717679/solving-a-combintorical-problem-using-generating-function); so if you've understood the answer you accepted there, then you shouldn't have any trouble with this.

Anyway, to answer your final question, just note that 
$$\sum_{n \ge 2} a_{n+1} x^n = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \ge 2} a_{n+1} x^{n+1} = \frac1x \sum_{m \ge 3} a_m x^m = \frac1x (F(x) - a_0 - a_1x - a_2 x^2)$$

(But note that there is an error in your calculation: when $\displaystyle F(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0}a_n x^n$, you must write either 
$$F(x) = 2 + 10x + \sum_{n \ge 2} a_n x^n$$ 
or 
$$F(x) = 2 + 10x + \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n+2} x^{n+2},$$
not 
$$\displaystyle F(x) = 2 + 10x + \sum_{n \ge 2} a_{n+2} x^{n+2}$$
as you have.)

---

If you do it correctly, you get 
$$\begin{align}
F(x) 
&= 2 + 10x + \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n+2} x^{n+2} \\
&= 2 + 10x + \sum_{n \ge 0} (2a_{n+1} + 3a_n) x^{n+2} \\
&= 2 + 10x + 2x\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n+1} x^{n+1} + 3x^2 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n \\
&= 2 + 10x + 2x(F(x) - a_0) + 3x^2 F(x) \\
\end{align}$$
giving
$$F(x)(1 - 2x - 3x^2) = 2 + 6x
$$
or
$$F(x) = \frac{2 + 6x}{1 - 2x - 3x^2} = \frac{2 + 6x}{(1 + x)(1 - 3x)} = \frac{3}{1-3x} - \frac{1}{1+x}$$
and therefore 
$$a_n = 3^{n+1} - (-1)^n$$

Answer (score 0):

Define $F(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$ (starting indices at 0 is more comfortable), and write your recurrence as:
$$
a_{n + 2} = 2 a_{n + 1} + 3 a_n \qquad a_0 = 2, a_1 = 2 
$$
(the value for $a_0$ comes from running the recurrence backwards).

Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, and recognize:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 2} z^n
  &= \frac{F(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
  &= \frac{F(z) - a_0}{z}
\end{align}
to get:
$$
\frac{F(z) - 2 - 2 z}{z^2}
  = 2 \frac{F(z) - 2}{z} + 3 F(z)
$$
I.e.,
$$
F(z) = 2 \frac{1 - z}{(1 + z) (1 - 3 z)}
     = \frac{1}{1 - 3 z} + \frac{1}{1 + z}
$$
This is just two geometric series:
$$
a_n = 3^n + (-1)^n
$$
This agrees with the initial values given.